# swiftで、2次元連想配列をjsonでPOSTする方法

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

以下の連想配列 dicを post送信しようとしていますが上手くいきません。

連想配列 dicは以下の要素を持ちます。

```
key `"id"`         : `<文字列>`
key `"cond_array"` : `<配列>`
```

また、配列cond_arrayは、文字配列の配列で今回のコードでは以下の要素を持ちます。

```
cond_array[0]=["2","8","1"]
cond_array[1]=["2","3"]
```

---

このデータをPOST送信しようとしていますがうまくいきません。
教えていただける方おられましたらご教授願います。

書いたコードは以下になります。

```
    let URL = NSURL(string: "aaa.php/")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var data2: [String] = ["2", "8", "1"]
    var data3: [String] = ["2", "3"]
    var array1 = [data2, data3]
    var dic: [String: AnyObject] = [
        "id": "abc",
        "cond_array": array1
    ]
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dic, options: nil, error: nil)        
    let connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!    
    var data: NSData! = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

受信はの様ですが、php側のコードはどうなっていますか？

以下でも少し触れましたが、jsonを受け取る場合はストリームから受け取るようにしなければなりません。

echo file_get_contents('php://input');

[JavascriptをつかったAjaxのPost処理](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2272/javascript%E3%82%92%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9Fajax%E3%81%AEpost%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86/2279#2279)

それ以外ではurlが "aaa.php/" とスラッシュで終わっていますがこちらも問題ないでしょうか。

送信結果確認のために、errorも受け取るようにした方が良いかと思います。

---

## 追記

一応、以下の様なコードをplaygroundから送信できることは確認しました。

```
import UIKit

let URL = NSURL(string: "YOURURL/sample.php")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
var data2: [String] = ["2", "8", "1"]
var data3: [String] = ["2", "3"]
var array1 = [data2, data3]
var dic: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "id": "abc",
    "cond_array": array1
]


// jsonヘッダの追加。無くても取得できましたが、あった方が良いかと思います。
//request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
//request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dic, options: nil, error: nil)

// 普通のPOSTの場合
// request.HTTPBody = "id=1".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


let connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: nil, startImmediately: false)!
var error: NSError?
var response: NSURLResponse?
var data: NSData! = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

println(NSString(data:data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

sample.phpは以下の様なコードです。

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);  // POSTの確認。JSONには不要。  

echo file_get_contents('php://input');  // JSONを取得するため。
```

Comment: 作成したコードが正しいこと、jsonヘッダがあったほうが良いこと、errorも受けたほうが良いこと、PHP側のコード例がとても役に立ちました。
試しましたら、またこちらにて報告させていただきます。
大変感謝いたします。
ありがとうございます。